# Load different css on different pages

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

I'm trying to find a solution to this problem:

I'm using a template with different css includes based on page, ex:

```
Login uses login.css
Home uses home.css
```

If I load both css the login page is broken, because styles are overwritten by home.css
So I need to load or require login.css if the route or the component is Login and the other one when is Home.

If I load both webpack builds a global css with both files, and everything is broken...

I tried to require the css in componentDidMount, but I think that is not the way :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like both these styles are quite specific to the pages, so why not simply namespace them?

Within your templates, have a .login/.home class, and use this as the namespace within the css. If you're using sass, this is as simple as wrapping all the sass in the class. Otherwise, you can go through and add the class to the beginning of all the elements/clases.

Comment: yes I can do that, but they are files from a template, so I will need to modify them on every template's update, I would like to know if there are smarter solutions :)

Answer (score 0):

*This is a more generic approach to combine CSS files, without depending on technologies like SASS or reactjs.*

I assume, if you combine the two CSS files, you are using Grunt or similar tool, to automate that task. So automatically updating the CSS files should be OK for you, even though they are from an external source and you want to use updated versions without making manual changes.

I also assume, you are using classes to style your pages, so there are no tag based styles in your CSS. Because you cannot rename the tags in the CSS file without braking it or make larger changes to your code.

If my assumptions are true, you could use something like grunt-css-prefix. It can add prefixes to your CSS classes for the login page, like in this snippet.

Original CSS file content:

```
.foo,
.bar,
h1 {
  display: none;
}
```

CSS file content after running the Grunt script:

```
.login-foo,
.login-bar,
h1 {
  display: none;
}
```

Just use the `login-foo` like class names in your Login-HTML and you are good to go.

For more details on how to use grunt-css-prefix, please have a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-css-prefix.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't have any problems if you use different css classes for your views and just style the elements based on those classes.

The best way to load css in react is to do it by components, if you got a component **login.jsx**, in your styles folder (or whatever folder you're using to hold your styles) create a sass partial **_login.scss** and add the css selectors and styles for that given component, and do that for every component in your react application.

Then you just include those partials into a main.scss file and that's the file you want to load into your react app.

Here's an example of a main.scss file with some sass partials.

```
@import 'base/variables';
@import 'base/defaults';
@import 'components/login';
@import 'components/home';
```

That's a good and clean way to work with styles in react, of course you will need to configure your webpack in order to get sass to work in your application.

Take a look at [this](https://medium.com/@srinisoundar/setting-up-environment-for-react-sass-es2015-babel-with-webpack-2f77445129#.467pxxgd8) and [this](https://www.bensmithett.com/smarter-css-builds-with-webpack/) for more info.

Comment: my project is already structured in this way, but I'm using an external template, not built for react, so I'm running into some issues, like that

Comment: Oh I see, could you be more specific on that template you're using?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using React Helmet ([react-helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet))

Here is a quick example how to do that:

**Usage**

```
import {Helmet} from 'react-helmet';

<Helmet>
    <meta charSet="utf-8" />
    <title>My Title</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/example" />
</Helmet>
```

The  component injects plain HTML elements into the  tag of the application. his can include meta, title, link, style, or any other HTML tags that are acceptable within the head section.

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import Login from "./Pages/Login";
import Home from "./Pages/Home";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Login</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/home/">Home</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

        <Route path="/" exact component={Login} />
        <Route path="/home/" component={Home} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**Home.js**

```
import React from "react";

import "../styles.css";

function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Home Page</h1>
      <p>This is the Home Page</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

**Login.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";

function Login() {
  return (
    <div className="login container">
      <Helmet>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="login.css" />
      </Helmet>
      <h1>Login</h1>
      <p>This is the login page</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

In the Login page, we have a `<Helmet />` Component and we are injecting our link tag with the login stylesheet into the head.